# Joining on the same table more than once

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm probably being a bit dumb, hopefully someone can help.

I have a simple 2 column user table (ID, USERNAME).
I have a comments table for images (COMMENT, COMMENTFROM, COMMENTTO)

COMMENTFROM is the ID of the user who made the comment. COMMENTTO is the ID of the owner of the image that the comment was added to. Both users are held within the USERS table.

I want to pull out and display rows like this

```
"really nice photo" - to USERXYZ - from USER123**
```

This has puzzled me, because if I join the USERS table to the comments table on:

```
WHERE comments.userfrom = users.id
```

That only gets me one (or the other) of the 2 usernames I need per row. Is there a way I can get both?

I'm not even sure how I would search for this answer on SOF, apologies if it has been answered before. If anyone can point me in the right direction it would be appreciated :)

Comment: Please do not beat yourself up too much. Also, a more specific question title will help give a rough idea of what is going on.

Comment: Yeah, don't worry too much if you can't remember the name for a concept/design pattern :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to `JOIN` to the `users` table twice, and give them different identifiers (aka *aliases*) on each `JOIN` within your SQL.

```
SELECT 
    comment, 
    userFrom.username AS commentFrom,
    userTo.username AS commentTo
FROM comments 
JOIN users AS userFrom ON userFrom.ID = comment.commentFrom
JOIN users AS userTo ON userTo.ID = comment.commentTo
```

Comment: Ah as I live and breathe and learn :) I did not know you could do that - thank you for your help Fabian that is a lifesaver :)

Comment: @BigTed blew my mind the first time I figured out you could do that!

Comment: cracking answer, not just because it shows how to join the table twice, but also shows how to rename the common columns so they can be accessed separately after the SQL has been executed. Thank you so much.

Answer (score -1):

Please try following one

```
SELECT CONCAT(c.comment," - to ",
                        (SELECT USERNAME FROM user WHERE user.ID = c.COMMENTTO LIMIT 1),
                        " - from ",
                        (SELECT USERNAME FROM user WHERE user.ID = c.COMMENTFROM LIMIT 1)) FROM comments c
```