# JOINING more then once?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a table of users:`users`
I have another table `booths`

```
  users
  ===============================  
  ID    |    NAME        |   SID
  -------------------------------
  1          cillia          abcd
  2          Ted             efgh

 booth
 =====================================================
  BOOTH_ID      |  BOOTH_OWNER    |     BOOTH_MANAGER  
 -----------------------------------------------------
   1               1                    2
   2               2                    4
   3               1                    3
```

I would like to create a query that would make clear for a specific booth, the name of the manager and the name of the owner.
What is the best approach to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Joining on the same table more than once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17139554/joining-on-the-same-table-more-than-once)

Comment: I downvoted this, because this question has been asked so many times before and the duplicates can easily be found by just searching for you question's title in SO or Google. Ergo: doesn't show research effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would just link the `users` table to the `booth` table twice:

```
SELECT b.BOOTH_ID, s1.NAME AS BoothOwner, s2.NAME AS BoothManager
FROM booth b
INNER JOIN users s1 ON b.BOOTH_OWNER = s1.ID
INNER JOIN users s2 ON b.BOOTH_MANAGER = s2.ID
```